Is there a professional term for 1 over sampling rate?
I have a terminology question.
Say i'm using a sampling rate s which is in the units of samples/second
What is term for 1/s? i.e., the distance in seconds between two samples?
Thanks

It's the sampling period or sampling interval.
(By the way, also bold on the wikipedia page you get redirected to for "Sampling rate".)
